# C# - How to stop timer from within another function?

Tags: c#

I created a timer Element (timerA) and try to stop it inside a function:

```
public static string sendWebRequest(string URL) {...}
```

How can I achive this?

I tried it like this:

```
public static string sendWebRequest(string URL)
{
    ...
    timerA.Stop();
}
```

I get `The non-static field, method, or property "main.timerA" requires an object reference` (main is the name of the form).

So I tried it like this:

```
main.timerA.Stop();
```

But I get the same error.

Comment: your timerA is not a static variable, so you cant use it without an instance.

Comment: As the error says you timer is a non-static field, that means you need to have a reference to the instantiated main object.  Referring to the class name does not help.   Without seeing more of your code it is hard to help, but I suggest you iterate through the Application.OpenForms collection to find it.

Comment: This is a case when providing a [mcve] would be very useful. Then we can show you how you should code this up. Right now we can see the relationship between the code that contains `sendWebRequest` and `timerA`.

Comment: Also, why on Earth should `sendWebRequest` need to know anything about the timer that called it? It seems like code smell to me.

Answer (score 1):

If you have one particular Timer that is going to be used throughout the entire application you have to have that in static variable.

A static variable means that it is created in the class loader and will not have any other instances while creating objects. So the static timer will be used throughout the entire application if it is 'public'.

While this is not a nice approach to modify the timer directly inside other functions What you can do is to make sure your have a timer in static mode:

```
public static System.Timers.Timer ApplicationTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
```